# My number format in C# is not giving me a padded number

Tags: c#

I am using the following:

```
    public static SelectList GetOptions<T>(string value = null) where T : struct
    {
        var values = EnumUtilities.GetSpacedOptions<T>();
        var options = new SelectList(values, "Value", "Text", value);
        return options;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetSpacedOptions<T>(bool zeroPad = false) where T : struct
    {
        var t = typeof(T);
        if (!t.IsEnum)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Not an enum type");
        }
        var numberFormat = zeroPad ? "D2" : "g";
        var options = Enum.GetValues(t).Cast<T>()
            .Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = ((int) Enum.ToObject(t, x)).ToString(numberFormat),
                Text = Regex.Replace(x.ToString(), "([A-Z])", " $1").Trim()
            });
        return options;
```

My enum has values:

```
public enum DefaultStatus {
    Release = 0,
    Review = 1,
    InProgress = 2,
    Concept = 3,
    None = 99
};
```

From what I understand the number format should give my values of "01","02" etc but it's giving me ""1","2","3" ..

Is there something obvious I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You're calling your function with `zeroPad = false` here. What are you doing in your real code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `GetSpacedOptions` has optional parameter `zeroPad` with default value `false`.

Use

```
var values = EnumUtilities.GetSpacedOptions<T>(true);
```

instead of

```
var values = EnumUtilities.GetSpacedOptions<T>();
```